# Get entity from table where method equals to true in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get entity from users table if the predefined method equal to true.

I have this method in my User model

```ruby
def self.expert?
  return self.has_role? :domain_expert
end
```

And I'm trying to do this query

```ruby
users = User.where(:expert? => true)
```

The error

```
 no such column: users.expert?
```

How to do this query?

EDIT:

I'm using rolify gem

In Role Model

```ruby
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
```

Comment: what columns do you have in your user model?

Comment: I'm using devise and cancan, I don't want to add column for that.

Comment: but where are you looking for the true or false value if you don't have anything set with a true or false? when you query something you are telling rails to look in its database.

Comment: Tell us more about your db structure, roles is a relationship? Is it a column? etc.. I dropped my crystal ball this morning

Comment: can you show how `has_role?` is defined?

Comment: @iRichLau Aha, I don't have this column in my users table, Is there anther way?

Comment: why you are combining class method with instance variable? **def self.expert?** no need to use self in this method def.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rolify gem version higher than 3.2 then it's just

```
User.with_role(:domain_expert)
```

If you set up cancan roles as described here: [Role Based Authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization)

Then you should query like

```
User.where(:role => :domain_expert)
```

You can also define scope for this and call it like User.domain_experts

If you are using Rolify gem before version 3.2 or made separate model like described here: [Separate Role Model](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model)

Then you should query like

```
Role.where(:name => :domain_expert).users
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the rolify gem readme, there's a `with_role` scope

```
User.with_role(:domain_expert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it :).

I must joins the two table (users and roles)

```ruby
User.joins(:roles).where("name = ?", "domain_expert")
```

This solved my problem :).